# jQuery ajax reloads the page in Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a project in Yii2. I want to click a button and send data to php script using ajax. But the page is reloading nomatter what I do.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#signup_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/user/test",
            data: { id: "2"}
        })
    });
```

How do send the data without reloading the page?

Comment: Also, if I remove $.ajax({}) statement, the page is not reloading

Comment: It depends on how you set your Form too. Add your Form source code to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

In place of binding "click" event with submit button, bind "submit" event with form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one of the semicolon at the end of ajax call..........try this

```
$('#signup_btn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/user/test",
                data: { id: "2"}
            });
        });
```